# Jquery get current full path

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a path like this:

http://www.domain.com/admin/item.php?id=4&action=edit

And want to get that path, compare with every element of my menu, and add the class "active" to the current menu item, like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/admin/item.php?id=1&action=edit">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/admin/item.php?id=2&action=edit">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/admin/item.php?id=3&action=edit">Item 3</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="http://www.domain.com/admin/item.php?id=4&action=edit">Item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.domain.com/admin/item.php?id=5&action=edit">Item 5</a></li>
...
</ul>
```

How can I do it with Jquery?  The most functions I tried, neither of them can get the full pathname (with all vars)

Comment: Do you really need the full path? I would use relative paths unless you do a find and replace on deployment.

Comment: This seems like bad form. There's loads of things that would make this fail: escaped characters, fragment identifiers (#) in the URL, etc. It'd be better if you were handling this from the PHP side of things.

Comment: If I could do with PHP, but this piece of code is loaded with include, don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the anchor element with the href property set to the given path. Then use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to add `active` as the class for the selected anchor element. If you want the full current path of the page you are on, [use `location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location), but note that this will include the current hash too, if there is one. Also, I would suggest selecting the menu by ID, so add an ID to your nav menu.

```
function setCurrentMenuPathAsActive(path){
   $(".nav li a[href='" + path + "']").addClass("active");
}

setCurrentMenuPathAsActive(location.href);
```

Comment: The problem is that "location.href" always trims my url after the file extension's ".php" ....file.php*******trimmed*****

Comment: @RafaMérida I am getting the query string included in location.href. I am testing on Chrome on Mac OS X. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Exactly the same browser, the same OS. Should I need to trim the "http://www.domain.com/" part?

Comment: I just tested on this very page. I added `?a=5&b=7 to the end of this url and tried location.href it got the full domain including the query string. http://i.imgur.com/pQ8eo.png

Comment: For some reason, the script is not working for me. Can be because my menu links have relative paths? This style: 
<a href="item.php?id=4&action=edit">Item 4</a>

The code retrieves the full path string, but doesn't match the item link, don't know why.

Comment: Try alert(location.href) to confirm you are getting the same path as in your nav link

Comment: The alert outputs the right string, but my links are relative and doesn't have the "h t t p ://domain/" part.

Comment: In that case (in which case your question needs to be changed) try `location.pathname + location.search`

Comment: I'm not getting it. Your code works, but I think that the problem is caused by my localhost and the way of building the relative menu links. Thank you very much, I'll try to do it with PHP instead.

Comment: Finally found it!! I wanted to addClass to the parent element, the **<li>** object:
    `$(function(){
  function setCurrentMenuPathAsActive(path){
     $(".nav li a[href='" + path + "']").parent().addClass("active");
  }
  setCurrentMenuPathAsActive(location.href);
  console.log(location.href);
});`